# Highchart How to set pie chart sliced distance gap wider to one another

Tags: highcharts

My pie chart slice is too narrow to one another i would like to create a distance gap between slice. What is the command to do that

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you may use is slicedOffset, it will give you a chance to slice your point.

```
series: [{
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Browser share',
  slicedOffset: 30,
  borderColor: 'white',
  data: [
    ['Firefox', 75.0], {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 12.8,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }
  ]
}]
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/t8cqev0r/2/

You can also use edgeColor and edgeWidth for getting your pie points separated:

```
pie: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    depth: 35,
    edgeWidth: 5,
    edgeColor: 'white'
  }
},
```

Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t8cqev0r/3/

Comment: thank you for the solution... I have another question do you know how to make specific pie sliced to adjust its own color...let say as in your example chrome is red and firefox black..

Comment: You can add color parameter directly in your point. Look into this example: http://jsfiddle.net/t8cqev0r/4/

Comment: Sorry i have another question if i want to apply the specific color coding in jaspers ad hoc how should i write is it like so ploOptions.series.color then the value is "Firefox", "black"